# What is the maximum entropy joint Bernoulli distribution with fixed covariances and individual means?

Tags: joint-distribution, information-theory, bernoulli-distribution, maximum-entropy

We have Bernoulli variables $B_i$ with known means $E(B_i)$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma = (cov(B_i, B_j))$. What joint distribution would have the maximum entropy?

Comment: Did you try the usual Lagrange multipliers method? What happened?